# How to use bulk feature in Berkeley DB?

Tags: c++, bulkinsert, berkeley-db, bulk

currently I am working a bit with Berkeley DB and try to understand the C++ bulk feature that is build in. Problem is I have no idea how to use this feature. There are no C++ examples (only those bloated C examples) or unit tests I could use to understand it.

I would like to use especially the DbMultipleKeyDataBuilder, which should be filled with data that comes from a std::map.

How should I initialize the constructor parameter of the DbMultipleKeyDataBuilder? What happens with the data parameter of Db::put method? Should it be empty or NULL?

If anyone has used successfully those classes, could you please provide some small examples?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Martin

EDIT:

Ok, so far I have following code

```
void
Storage::bulkInsert(
        TransactionI& txn,
        const Entries& entries) const
{
    if(entries.size() <= 0)
        return;

    char buffer[1024];
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    Dbt multipleDbts;
    multipleDbts.set_ulen(1024 * sizeof(char));
    multipleDbts.set_data(&buffer);
    multipleDbts.set_flags(DB_DBT_USERMEM | DB_DBT_BULK);

    DbMultipleKeyDataBuilder keyDataBuilder(multipleDbts);

    Dbt dbtKey;
    Dbt dbtValue;

    for(typename Entries::const_iterator iter = entries.begin();
            iter != entries.end(); ++iter)
    {
        uint64_t tmpKey = iter->first;
        const std::string& tmpValue = iter->second;
        keyDataBuilder.append(
                &tmpKey, sizeof(uint64_t),
                const_cast<char*>(tmpValue.c_str()), tmpValue.length()+1);
    }
    this->getDbHandle().put(txn.getDbTxn(), &multipleDbts, 0, DB_MULTIPLE_KEY);
}
```

But what about the buffer of the Dbt multipleDbts?! How should this buffer be created. Imagine I have key/value pairs where key is an integer and value a string of different lengths?

Answer (score 0):

Martin,

In case you didn't see it, Emily [replied to this question](http://bit.ly/g871im) on the BDB OTN Forums. It's a great place to get information and more closely monitored than Stackoverflow. You'll find an active developer community there as well.

Regards,

Dave

Comment: Dave, 
thanks for the info. I didn't see the solution of Emily. As I see I have mostly done it correct. Just the flags are unnecessary :) But actually she didn't answer to my question. I was asking about the DbtMultipleKeyDataBuilder and not DbtMultipleDataBuilder. But anyway there should be offical examples/tests for the C++ API. Martin